# Can't power-down USB device

Tags: linux, usb, device, power-management

Here's my problem:

`mint power # uname -a
Linux mint 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
mint power # pwd
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb5/5-2/power
mint power # cat autosuspend autosuspend_delay_ms control level persist 
1
1000
auto
auto
1
mint power # echo on >level
mint power # echo off >level
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
mint power # echo suspend >level
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
mint power #`

Why can't I power-off the USB device? Clearly the hardware has the capability!

Comment: What are you expecting to get by "powering down" the device? Most USB hosts can't actually cut power to ports, if that's what you mean…

Answer (score 2):

`off` and `suspend` are not valid settings, and the `level` file is deprecated.

Try the documentation:

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt